# Производительность WEB приложения

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, веб-программирование, java-ee

Занимаюсь разработкой системой тестирования заданий. Возникла потребность в комнате администратора. Сделал ее похожей на админку wordpress, вот она:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все вкладки сделаны на одной странице переход происходит с помощью JS. Но уже сейчас 350 строк кода HTML, уже порядка 300 строк кода JS, ну и сервлеты Java со стороны сервера. В связи с этим боюсь не станет ли это все виснуть, когда будет много данных, когда еще добавится много скриптов и Ajax. Не может хотелось бы разбивать на разные страницы, хотелось бы чтобы плавно все переходило без перезагрузки страницы. Но может этого нельзя делать? Может кто-нибудь подскажет на счет этого вопроса?

Comment: Триста строк это очень смешное количество ни о чём :)

Comment: Вопрос скорее не в количестве кода, а в качестве. Приложение может весить в сжатом виде (сжатом!) и мегабайт и два и браузер это съедает  , однако если приложение перерисовывает весь экран каждые 10 мс , то не поможет ничего

Answer (score 1):

Для начала - 300 строк это немного, а теперь к делу. Вы по сути хотите single page приложение сделать, тогда уж лучше не HTML + JS использовать, а взять React или аналог, который будет генерировать контент по мере поступления. И да, все данные тянуть сразу не стоит, будет тормозить нещадно, лучше тянуть с сервера только то, что необходимо прямо сейчас

Comment: На react все гораздо проще будет и в каком смысле генерировать контент? Могли бы посоветовать хорошие источники для его изучения? И придется тогда весь код переписывать... Уже много на jQuery написано и HTML

Comment: @БалунВладимир https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html документация. Генерировать это в смысле, проще на примере расписать. то есть у вас есть данные, которые надо вывести в таблицу. С помощью реактовских компонентов описываете таблицу, количество строк вас не волнует - в зависимости от количества записей они или добавятся, или уберутся. Опять же - при обновлении одной ячейки не будет перезагружаться всё, как это делает JQuery. В идеале еще Saga прикрутить можно, для большей гибкости, но тут уже как захотите)

Comment: Понял, скажите но JQuery же можно будет оставить там для переходов между меню? Или же вообще сносить его? И оставлять только React?

Comment: @БалунВладимир сносить